# System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x8007202B): A referral was returned from the server

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am getting the exception (System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x8007202B): A referral was returned from the server.) while trying to read the manager's display name from Active Directory.

**Exception Snapshot:**

[image]

The exception is occurring while doing the following check,

```
if (grp != null && grp.Properties != null && grp.Properties["displayname"] != null && grp.Properties["displayname"].Value != null)
```

**Code:**

```
if (foundEntry.Properties["manager"] != null && foundEntry.Properties["manager"].Value != null)
{
    DirectoryEntry grp = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + foundEntry.Properties["manager"].Value);
    if (grp != null && grp.Properties != null && grp.Properties["displayname"] != null && grp.Properties["displayname"].Value != null)
    {
        adresult.SupervisorName = grp.Properties["displayname"].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

**Group Property**

When I debug grp.Properties, I am seeing the following:

[image]

Am I missing anything? What could be the cause of this issue?

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: when you use the debugger.. what is the value of `grp.Properties as well as grp.Properties["displayname"]` are you familiar with `PrincipalContext`

Comment: I have attached the screenshot of grp.Properties. Any suggestions?

Comment: sounds like you need to iterate the `DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection` do a foreach on that to drill down to the properties you need just at first glance

Comment: I don't think your `grp` is populated correctly. When you're creating the `DirectoryEntry`  after call `grp.RefreshCache()`.  See if that throws you any errors.